# Time slider for image service

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, timeslider, image-service

I am trying to make a time slider for an imagery service that would take the time stops from the imagery dates. The imagery service has been published from a mosaic dataset that has a field called "AcquisitionDate". I tried to re-use a piece of code that was written by someone else for a feature layer but it doesn t work for my imagery layer: the time slider shows:"No time extent". I am wondering if for my image service I can use the attribute table field ("AcquisitionDate") or I have to work with TimeInfo?

I attach here the code.

```
<html>
```

```
<title>TimeSlider widget | Sample | ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.19</title>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://js.arcgis.com/next/esri/themes/light/main.css"
/>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/next/"></script>

<style>
  html,
  body,
  #viewDiv {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #timeSlider {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    bottom: 20px;
  }

  #titleDiv {
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 36;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<script>
  require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/widgets/TimeSlider",
    "esri/layers/ImageryLayer",
    "esri/smartMapping/statistics/uniqueValues"
  ], function (Map, MapView, TimeSlider, ImageryLayer, uniqueValues) {
    const map = new Map({
      basemap: "topo-vector"
    });

    // center around the AOI
    const view = new MapView({
      container: "viewDiv",
      map,
      center: [92.473, 21.075],
      zoom: 10
    });

    
    const layer = new ImageryLayer({
      url:
        "https://someText.org/arcgis/rest/services/My_Imagery/ImageServer"
    });
    map.add(layer);
    // time slider widget initialization
    // add a new time slider without view settings
    const timeSlider = new TimeSlider({
      container: "timeSlider",
      mode: "instant",
      timeVisible: true,
      playRate: 200
    });
    timeSlider.watch("timeExtent", () => {
      const start = timeSlider.timeExtent.start.getTime();
      const where = `AcquisitionDate = ${start}`;
      layerView.filter = {
        where
      };
    });

    let layerView;
    let dates = [];
    view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function (lv) {
      uniqueValues({
        layer: layer,
        field: "AcquisitionDate"
      }).then(function (response) {
        // prints each unique value and the count of features containing that value
        let infos = response.uniqueValueInfos;
        infos.forEach(function (info) {
          const dt = new Date(info.value);
          dates.push(dt);
        });

        var randomDates = [
          new Date(2021, 0, 11, 13, 52, 59, 452),
          new Date(2021, 0, 11, 13, 32, 58, 956),
          new Date(2021, 0, 12, 13, 55, 33, 216),
          new Date(2021, 0, 11, 14, 02, 56, 873),
          new Date(2021, 0, 11, 14, 22, 44, 315),
          new Date(2021, 0, 11, 14, 44,  21, 273),
          new Date(2021, 0, 11, 15, 02, 24, 093),
          new Date(2021, 0, 11, 17, 49, 56, 344),
          new Date(2021, 0, 12, 1, 08, 45, 504),
          new Date(2021, 0, 12, 1, 54, 36, 290),
          new Date(2021, 0, 12, 8, 31, 16, 087),
          new Date(2021, 0, 11, 16, 34, 05, 781),
          new Date(2000, 0, 11, 16, 36, 11, 802),
        ];
        
        var date_sort_asc = function (date1, date2) {
          if (date1 > date2) return 1;
          if (date1 < date2) return -1;
          return 0;
        };
        randomDates.sort(date_sort_asc);
        randomDates.forEach(function(dt){
          console.log(dt.toLocaleString())
        });

        timeSlider.stops = { dates };

        // set the time slider's full time extent to cover
        // imagery dates
        timeSlider.fullTimeExtent = {
          start: dates[0],
          end: dates[dates.length - 1]
        };

        const start = dates[0].getTime();
        const where = `AcquisitionDate = ${start}`;

        layerView = lv;
        layerView.filter = {
          where
        };
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Imagery slider